# Visual Studio 2017 can't edit and continue debug correctly

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017

I have installed 3 days ago VS2017. I have to disable(!) "Edit and continue" option to Edit my code during debugging.

The issue is that, during debugging, if I add a new call to a function or I add a blank line, debugger ignores it.
It continues to run original code.

Anyone can Help me?

Comment: Disable? Why you disable it, as i know we must enable it so that we can edit code and make changes work during debugging?

Comment: Hi, any update? What about the result if you enable the "Edit and continue" option, will it continue to run original code? If there has any update, feel free to share here my friend.

Comment: Hello, This is a very un-intuitive action, but I read in an article that if you uncheck "Edit and continue", you really can edit and continue, but debugger run old code.

Comment: Hi friend, I suggest you can give it a try. I create a new C# console project to test, after I enabled the "Edit and continue" option, I can edit my code when debugging, and debugger will run the code line I add, it helps me to find the result of a function when I use different input.

Comment: And if possible, have you checked the info in the article, which version of vs does it indicate?

Comment: Hello, I tried with a console application as suggested. It works. Then I use an "old" web app I create with VS 2012: it doesn't work. Articles I read about "disable edit and continue" are related to VS 2012. I can't continue in this way... very desperate

Comment: Hi, I understand this behavior. In different versions of vs, they can be some different. As you mentioned, that's a unique behavior in vs2012. But for vs2017, if we disable it, then debugger will ignore the changes.

Comment: And glad that you've found the cause of it. If my answer helps, please help mark it as answer, more members with similar issue could benefit from it. Thank you.

Comment: I will mark it as answer, but my issue still exists. I suppose I will format my laptop, install VS 2017 and hope to avoid losing data

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Hope you can have good journey with vs2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> disable(!) "Edit and continue" option to Edit my code during debugging

In VS2017,whether enable or disable this option, we can edit the code during debugging

> The issue is that, during debugging, if I add a new call to a function
>   or I add a blank line, debugger ignores it. It continues to run
>   original code.

If we enable the option, add a call to DoSth(),like below:
[image]

The DoSth() will be executed. 
If we disable it, the debugger will ignore this change.

It's normal behaviour in VS2017.

Comment: I had to uncheck the option, then start application, then stop it, and then check it again. After that it worked!